# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /var/www/

Tags: mysql, class, warnings

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given
in /var/www/xxxxx/data/www/xxxxx.ru/xxxxx/classes/mysql.class.php on line 51
```

```
  public function query($query, $comment = "") {
    if ($this -> conn) {
        $this -> conn = $this -> connect();
    }
    $start = microtime();
    if (!($result = mysql_query($query, $this -> conn)))  // <<-- line 51
    {
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    $end*emphasized text* = microtime();
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (!$this -> conn) {` (!) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$conn` will most likely not be initialized.

Make sure, that you're setting $conn to `NULL` in the constructor and check against `if(!$this->conn)` (mind the exclamation mark) or do the connecting in the constructor.

With an error message like this, consider using `var_dump` to check the content of the variable in question.

Also, just for the sake of completeness: The `mysql`-functions are superseded by the `mysqli`-functions. Please consider using those instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here:

```
if ($this->conn) {
    $this->conn = $this -> connect();
}
```

It should be `if (!$this->conn) {`. Otherwise `$this->conn` is never initialized and you pass not a resourse to subsequent `mysql_query`.

( *I believe you declared it as an empty string in your class: `public $conn = '';`*)

By the way, you are aware that `mysql` extension is deprecated, right?

Comment: [link](http://studio35.ru/mysql.class.zip) I think if I show you the whole file will be more clear in what may be a bug